# Countifs across BO Webi merge like correlated subquery

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'd like to do a `countifs` across a merge in BusinessObjects webi. I have two different data sets, which are merged on dimension `SID`. One data source which would be the source for the outer query, known as "Contacts", has the following columns:

- `SID` (number, dimension)
- `Contact Date` (date, dimension)
- `Contact Type` (string, dimension)

The other data source, known as "Incidents", has the following columns:

- `SID` (number, dimension)
- `Incident Date` (date, dimension)

I would like to create a report in Webi based on the "Contacts" data source (maybe using merge, detail variables) with the following columns:

- `SID` (number, dimension)
- `Contact Date` (date, dimension)
- `Contact Type` (string, dimension)
- **`Incidents Influenced`** (*VARIABLE* countifs of records in "Incidents" where the following is true:)

```
[Incidents].[SID] = [Contacts].[SID]

[Incidents].[Incident Date]<=([Contact].[Contact Date]+7)

[Incidents].[Incident Date]>=[Contact].[Contact Date]
```

Any thoughts? I've been trying to do a detail variable with count() where, but this doesn't seem to be working. I am using BI Platform 4.2, Webi. I have researched many websites external to Stack overflow, such as [Variable to count Merged dimensions](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3448042) and [count formula in webi report](http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/businessobjects-reportinganalysis-l/count-formula-in-webi-report-3178987).

I have also looked at these two Stack Overflow articles, [Business Objects CountIf by cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981211/business-objects-countif-by-cell-reference) and [Business Objects WEBI 3 universes in one report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826258/business-objects-webi-3-universes-in-one-report). However, none of these show how, at least in a way I am able to understand, how to overcome a context error that seems to occur whenever I create detail variables and measures across the `SID` merge.

Here are what the two data sources would look like, as well as the desired output on the report:

```
CONTACTS
SID     Contact Date     Contact Type
1        8/1/2017        ONB
1        8/15/2017       SCB
2        8/14/2017       ONB
3        8/19/2017       ONB
4        9/1/2017        SCB

INCIDENTS
SID     Incident Date
1       8/1/2017
1       8/7/2017
1       8/9/2017
1       8/21/2017
1       9/1/2017
1       10/1/2017
2       8/15/2017
4       9/2/2017

**DESIRED OUTPUT ON REPORT
SID     Contact Date     Contact Type     Incidents Influenced
1        8/1/2017        ONB               2
1        8/15/2017       SCB               1
2        8/14/2017       ONB               1
3        8/19/2017       ONB               0
4        9/1/2017        SCB               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Amit Kumar from SAP [answered my question here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/352011/how-do-i-make-a-countifs-across-business-objects-w.html). Here is the solution he provided.

> *« Merge the SID objects and drag in the final table.*
>
> *Drag Contact Date & Contact Type objects in the final table.*
>
> *Create detail variable for Contact date as "V Contact Date" and for Incident date as "V Incident Date".*
>
> *Right click on the table->Format table-> checked the checkbox "Show rows with empty dimensions"*
>
> *Drag below formula for calculated column and see. »*
>
> `=Sum(If([V Incident Date]<=RelativeDate([ V Contact Date];7) And ([V Incident Date]>=[ V Contact Date])) Then 1 Else 0)`